# Linux VM as a USB device

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, embedded-linux, kvm

I am trying to develop a USB device with embedded linux and based on the [gadget api](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/). Is it possible to have a VM that runs this embedded linux and it shows up on the host's (virtual) USB hub ?

Comment: *" it shows up on the host's USB hub ?"* -- Not possible.  PCs only have USB host controllers (AFAIK), but a USB gadget would require a USB device controller.

Comment: I want the VM to have a device controller and the host to have a (virtual) host controller connected virtually.